# Make mongoose update all specified keys of an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a shopping website and we keep track of phones left in storage using something like this:

```
[
    {
        "product_name": "Y6s",
        "product_brand": "huawei",
        "product_variations": [
            {
                "product_color_name": "black",
                "product_stock": 22
            },
            {
                "product_color_name": "blue",
                "product_stock": 10
            }
        ]
    },
    
    {
        "product_name": "Y6 prime",
        "product_brand": "huawei",
        "product_variations": [
            {
                "product_color_name": "brown",
                "product_stock": 12
            },
            {
                "product_color_name": "blue",
                "product_stock": 5
            },
            {
                "product_color_name": "red",
                "product_stock": 10
            }
        ]
    }
    
]
```

In some cases I want to be able to make all of `product_stock`s back to zero (like when the shop is closed). I tried using this code

```
Phone.updateMany(null, {$set: {"product_variations.$.product_stock": 0}}, function(err){console.log(err);});
```

but it does not work and returns an error: `The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [$ positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) requires a filtering condition, what you need is the [positional all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#up._S_%5B%5D) operator:

```
Phone.updateMany(null, {$set: {"product_variations.$[].product_stock": 0}}, function(err){console.log(err);});
```